# How often do you need to register_post_type?

Tags: custom-post-types, plugins, plugin-development, hooks, performance

Assuming you write a plugin and hook into [activation / deactivation](https://developer.wordpress.org/plugins/the-basics/activation-deactivation-hooks/) to [register_post_type](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/register_post_type) is that good enough? Or do you need to do it every [init](https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/init)?

I'm looking for perf boosts and I want to reduce unnecessary calls.

[GenerateWP](https://generatewp.com/post-type/) uses `add_action( 'init', 'custom_post_type', 0 );` so that might be as early as I might want to register it.

**FINDINGS**

- [@s-ha-dum](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/212326/84219):

  > `register_post_type` needs to be called on every page load
  >
  > The `post` data itself is kept in the database, but the registration tells the PHP what to do with it.
- [@pieter-goosen](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/212327/84219):

  > Build in types are actually registered twice on every page load (due to localization that is only available on `init`)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`register_post_type` needs to be called on every page load-- `init` seems to be fine and [is the hook used in the Codex sample](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/register_post_type#Example). The post data itself is kept in the database, but the registration tells the PHP what to do with it. Most of the post type information-- the `$labels`, the `$args`-- are not kept in the database to my knowledge (though I would agree that there *might be* an argument for doing so), so without that registration code Core doesn't really know about the post type.

You can pretty easily test this yourself by registering the type and then commenting the code.

Comment: Thanks. I didn't know if I was missing something.

Comment: Think of it like instantiating a `Class` and it will bother you less ;) For the record, though, I am not sure that storing in the DB would offer any performance improvement and I'd actually bet against it.

Comment: It seems more like encapsulation than instantiating

Answer (score 3):

All post types and taxonomies are registered on every page load, regardless being build in or not. There is really nothing you can do about that.

Build in types are actually registered twice on every page load (*due to localization that is only available on `init`*) , so trying to optimize custom types are quite useless.

As post types and taxonomies data are not stored in db, you are already saving on db calls, although you are dirtying global space with their data. I'm not really sure which is better here, adding extra db calls to an already insane amount of db calls per page load or adding even more junk to global space.

Wordpress was actually never meant to go mainstream when they started of, so many features was never well thought of. Some of the mess made in earlier version cannot be undone without breaking thousands of sites due to their backwards compatibilty policy.

If you really need to optimize your site, start with obvious stuff like queries, minimilizing scripts and styles, caching large amounts of data, etc etc. As for core functions, all you can really do is to submit proposals to improve performance of specific functionalities and hope that your proposals gets approved and included in future releases

Comment: That localization part is good to know.

Comment: So is the part that Wordpress registers build in types twice. It is like eating the same piece of meat twice ;-) Njammie. That is called good recycling

Comment: Right, registering twice because of localization, and that localization needs to happen after `init`. So would registering it before init still call on init for localization? Or assuming you remove localization from labels -- what internally gets localized?